# FontAwesome icon displays differently in the same windows

Tags: css, font-awesome

I have a strange thing happening and it seems to happen regardless of the browser.
we are using version 4.6.3. Here is a sample of the html:

```html
    <li data-id="316" class="nav-item nav-leaf selectable-nav-item">
    <x-icon>
 <svg class="fa fa-file-text-o">
  <use xlink:href="#fa-file-text-o">
  #shadow-root (closed)
  <svg id="fa-file-text-o" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" width="100%" height="100%">
         <path d="M819.196 212.054q15.625 15.625 26.786 42.411t11.161 49.107v642.857q0 22.321-15.625 37.946t-37.946 15.625h-750q-22.321 
   0-37.946-15.625t-15.625-37.946v-892.857q0-22.321 15.625-37.946t37.946-15.625h500q22.321 0 49.107 11.161t42.411 26.786zM571.429 
   75.893v209.821h209.821q-5.58-16.183-12.276-22.88l-174.665-174.665q-6.696-6.696-22.88-12.276zM785.714 928.571v-571.429h-232.143q-22.321 
   0-37.946-15.625t-15.625-37.946v-232.143h-428.571v857.143h714.286zM214.286 446.429q0-7.813 5.022-12.835t12.835-5.022h392.857q7.813 0 12.835 
   5.022t5.022 12.835v35.714q0 7.813-5.022 12.835t-12.835 5.022h-392.857q-7.813 0-12.835-5.022t-5.022-12.835v-35.714zM625 571.429q7.813 0 12.835 
   5.022t5.022 12.835v35.714q0 7.813-5.022 12.835t-12.835 5.022h-392.857q-7.813 0-12.835-5.022t-5.022-12.835v-35.714q0-7.813 
   5.022-12.835t12.835-5.022h392.857zM625 714.286q7.813 0 12.835 5.022t5.022 12.835v35.714q0 7.813-5.022 12.835t-12.835 5.022h-392.857q-7.813 
   0-12.835-5.022t-5.022-12.835v-35.714q0-7.813 5.022-12.835t12.835-5.022h392.857z"></path>
      /svg>
  </use>
 </svg>
    </x-icon>
    <span style="z-index:99" class="nav-text" id="tree-search_316_">waterproof sheeting</span></li>
    <li data-id="319" class="nav-item nav-leaf selectable-nav-item">
    <x-icon>
 <svg class="fa fa-file-text-o">
  <use xlink:href="#fa-file-text-o">
  #shadow-root (closed)
  <svg id="fa-file-text-o" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" width="100%" height="100%">
         <path d="M819.196 212.054q15.625 15.625 26.786 42.411t11.161 49.107v642.857q0 22.321-15.625 37.946t-37.946 15.625h-750q-22.321 
   0-37.946-15.625t-15.625-37.946v-892.857q0-22.321 15.625-37.946t37.946-15.625h500q22.321 0 49.107 11.161t42.411 26.786zM571.429 
   75.893v209.821h209.821q-5.58-16.183-12.276-22.88l-174.665-174.665q-6.696-6.696-22.88-12.276zM785.714 928.571v-571.429h-232.143q-22.321 
   0-37.946-15.625t-15.625-37.946v-232.143h-428.571v857.143h714.286zM214.286 446.429q0-7.813 5.022-12.835t12.835-5.022h392.857q7.813 0 12.835 
   5.022t5.022 12.835v35.714q0 7.813-5.022 12.835t-12.835 5.022h-392.857q-7.813 0-12.835-5.022t-5.022-12.835v-35.714zM625 571.429q7.813 0 12.835 
   5.022t5.022 12.835v35.714q0 7.813-5.022 12.835t-12.835 5.022h-392.857q-7.813 0-12.835-5.022t-5.022-12.835v-35.714q0-7.813 
   5.022-12.835t12.835-5.022h392.857zM625 714.286q7.813 0 12.835 5.022t5.022 12.835v35.714q0 7.813-5.022 12.835t-12.835 5.022h-392.857q-7.813 
   0-12.835-5.022t-5.022-12.835v-35.714q0-7.813 5.022-12.835t12.835-5.022h392.857z"></path>
      /svg>
  </use>
 </svg>
    </x-icon>
```

As can be seen both icons are set in the same way. This icon depics a page with a corner folded with 3 horizontal lines. some of the icons display correctly and others have their lines seemingly closer together. If I increase the size of the viewport using CTL+ mouse wheel the icons then look the same. It's only at the smaller size when the viewport is set to 100% or less the issue occurs.

Comment: This sounds like a pixel rounding issue to me, but I can't reproduce the issue myself. There's not much you can do if that is the case, other than either use the icon at a larger size, or modify the icon so that the lines fall at positions which will round nicely.

Comment: @DBS Yes, It looks as though you are right. I've managed to prove this as the case.